# Assembly alias and symbol

Tags: c, assembly, linker, static-linking

1.cpp:

```
int meth() {
    return 0;
}
__asm__(".global  meth_alias \n meth_alias  = meth");
__asm__(".global  meth_alias2 \n meth_alias2  = meth");
```

2.cpp:

```
int meth_alias();
int meth_alias2();
int test()
{
    return meth_alias()+ meth_alias2();
}
```

build:

```
g++ -c -fPIC 1.cpp
g++ -c -fPIC 2.cpp
g++ -o 12.so --shared 1.o 2.o
```

There should be symbols "meth_alias" and "meth_alias2" in 1.o, but how to print these symbols with nm/objdump/readelf? The existing command flags only display the alias as ONE undefined symbol called the original name "meth". Should't there be one entry for each alias?

Are alias just normal symbols in the symbol table, i.e. name + address and address are the same with the original method?

Comment: You forgot to account for name mangling I'd say.  The symbol for  `meth` is `_Z4methv` (SysV ABI), not `meth`.  Not sure why there is no entry for `meth_alis` and `meth_alias2` though.

Comment: If I declare all `meth...` functions as `extern "C"` to disable name mangling, it works as expected.

Comment: @fuz Name mangling is not the point here (i.e. minor problem), you can just replace meth symbol in the question with _Z4methv, problem still exist. But extern "C" really disable the "bug".

Comment: `extern "C"` is a red herring.  If I correct the symbol names in your `asm` statement to account for name mangling, everything works as expected in much the same way as when I use `extern "C"` to disable name mangling.  The real problem is that your inline assembly does not use the correct symbol names.  Both fixing the symbol names and using `extern "C"` fixes this.

Comment: BTW, what are you trying to achieve?  Consider using `#pragma weak` instead.

Comment: @fuz I'm using libtooling to scan sources which contain such motif. Why does the program compile - no undefined symbol? - Mismatched name=alias still work + nm doesn't work?

Comment: if you create a shared object, all undefined symbols are assumed to be supplied by some other object at link- or runtime; thus it is not wrong to have undefined symbols in a shared object.  The same would not work if you were to link an executable.  I suppose the assembler silently ignoring the unfulfillable assignment (there's no trace of it left in the object file) might be a bug.

Comment: @fuz Good to learn all the staff, thanks!